# ScrollView in iPhone interfacebuilder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, scrollview

I have put 14 items in scroll view but it gets stuck after 6 items. I have not put any code, just did all from interface builder (items are arranged vertically). I can see the items below but it jumps to 6 items when I release the touch. It is not that the scroll view is not working, it is just not showing as much I want it to show.

Has any-body got any idea what is happening? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be its too late, but here is how i solved it:

1. put the items in a UIView and stretch that view as much as it need to be stretched.
2. put that UIView in the scrollview.
3. put a scroll view in the main uiview, the height and width will be similar to uiview.

Answer (score 1):

Scrollview content size is not set properly. Use `setContentSize:` to set the content size of the scrollview

You added the content into scrollview so now you have to make scroll know to what size it shoul scroll and show the content

**Do**

Set an outlet and then add this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

From Docs

```
contentSize
The size of the content view.

@property(nonatomic) CGSize contentSize
Discussion
The unit of size is points. The default size is CGSizeZero.
```

Here is a [nice tutorial](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/) since you are a beginner .

Comment: I am new to iPhone, can you tell me from where to set it?

Comment: I am using xcode4.6.2. and I did everything of the scrollview from the interface builder. have not done any code for it yet.

Comment: You know how to creat an outlet and then that outlet add the code .Answer edited check it and tell weather it works

Comment: when i create an outlet, this line of code appears, @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *RegisterMainScroll; not sure where to put the code...

Comment: yes then replace scrollview in my code with RegisterMainScroll  and set the width and height to a larger value and test it

Comment: i've put this code in viewLoad: [_RegisterMainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 2000)]; but still same result :(

Comment: changed the height value to 5000, nothing changed :(

Comment: {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(_RegisterMainScroll == nil){
        NSLog(@"_RegisterMainScroll = null");
    }
    NSLog(@"_RegisterMainScroll != null");
    
    [_RegisterMainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 10000)];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}     //the output shows RegisterMainScroll != null, but it is behaving as before, it is not showing more items.

Comment: scrolling as it was before, showing only 6 items, not all 14. nothing changes if i change the value inside setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 10000)

Comment: the scrollview's outlet is mapped as RegisterMainScroll but i can access it through _RegisterMainScroll, do i have to do something to map these two variables? it is so confusing....

Comment: open the nib and right click on the scrollview drag teh referencing outlet to the  Files owner and it will discribe the list of supporting outlets .connec twitht the RegistermaniScroll

Comment: Try teh tutorial in the above link

Comment: the IBOutlet is mapped as it is supposed to be i guess, still no luck with proper scrolling

Comment: change some property of the scrollview and see it for yourself. set backgroundcolor of scrollview and see outlet is connected right

Comment: yes, [_RegisterMainScroll setScrollEnabled:true]; works fine for true or false. The scroll happens, it just bounces back to its original position as soon as i remove the touch. I am sure i am making some silly mistake. just cannot find it what :(

Answer (score 1):

You should set the content size of your scrollview.

e.g.

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollview.contentSize.width, heigth)];
```

Where set height that contains all your sub controls in scrollview.